# How to extract data based on user_id and purchase month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset from which I need to extract user and user data who purchased in two months Jan and Feb. Could you please help me with the code?

[image]

The desired output should be like this below

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can use a `groupby` to get the list of different purchase months :

```py
>>> df = df.sort_values(by='purchase_month', ascending=False)
>>> df_grouped = df.groupby(['user_id'])['purchase_month'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x))).reset_index()
>>> df_grouped['purchase_month'] = df_grouped['purchase_month'].astype(str)
>>> df_grouped
    user_id purchase_month
0   1       ['Feb', 'Jan']
1   2       ['Feb']
2   3       ['Feb', 'Jan']
3   4       ['mar', 'mar']
```

Then, we filter on customers buying in at least 2 different months :

```py
>>> valid_users = df_grouped[df_grouped['purchase_month'] == "['Feb', 'Jan']"]['user_id'].tolist()
>>> valid_users
[1, 3]
```

To finish, we can filter the first DataFrame with those users to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df[df["user_id"].isin(valid_users)].sort_values(by=["user_id"])
    user_id purchase_month  product
0   1       jan             football
3   1       feb             bed
2   3       feb             toaster
4   3       jan             printer
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i didnt mentioned it before there are other months also in, and this command check for 2 unique values regardless of the order (in my case that is jan and feb months only). that mean any combination of two unique values will be included in it.

Comment: I updated the answer, does it answer your question correctly ?

Comment: In your case it will only check for ['jan','feb'] pattern but customer may have for instance this ['jan','jan','feb'], ['feb','feb','jan'] the months are same jan and feb but it will not be included in the output. customer may have 10 purchases in jan and 3 in feb, they should be included in it.

Comment: Indeed ! I updated the answer to avoid this case, does it works on your side ?

Answer (score 0):

Filter:

```
df[(df["Purchase month"]=="Jan") | (df["Purchase month"]=="Feb")]
```

Sort:

```
df.sort_values(by=["user_id"])
```

Comment: I think in this case, if either of the statement is true it will select that data. I want only those users who made purchase in both jan and feb.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- yes, you're right -- I misread the question! But I see you have a couple of correct answers, so I feel less guilty about my carelessness :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `groupby` and create a list of months for each User id
2. Only keep rows where months include both Jan and Feb i.e. the set `{"Jan", "Feb"}` is a subset of months

```
months = df.groupby("User id")["Purchase month"].agg(list)
output = df[df["User id"].isin(months[months.map({"Jan", "Feb"}.issubset)].index)]

>>> output
   User id Purchase month   Product
0        1            Jan  Football
2        3            Feb   Toaster
3        1            Feb       Bed
4        3            Jan   Printer
```

Comment: output.month.value_counts() ,  it is giving other information as well look at the result of value_counts() feb    385079
jan    300149
dec    178864
mar    148089
nov     78052
oct     53159
apr     48198

Comment: I only want common users of month jan and feb

Comment: Yes - doesn't this give you exactly that? User id 1 and 3?

Comment: thank you very much its working the way I want.

Comment: acknowledged :)